# uwsgi: Can't stop a Flask app

Tags: python, multithreading, flask, uwsgi

I have a Flask app running on uwsgi. I start the app in Ubuntu with:

```
sudo service uwsgi start
```

When I try to stop the uwsgi I use:

```
sudo service uwsgi stop
```

The problem is that the stop action hangs for a long time, and when it's done I still see uwsgi workers using `ps -ef | grep uwsgi`.

Why doesn't the uwsgi workers exit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that Python threads don't die when the main thread exits, unless they are daemon threads.

The solution is to daemonize any background thread:

```python
t = Thread(target=print_queue_size, args=())
t.setDaemon(True) # Does the trick
t.start()
```